# Ruby BigDecimal sanity check (floating point newb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, floating-point, bigdecimal

Is my understanding correct that with Ruby `BigDecimal` types (even with varying precision and scale lengths) should calculate accurately or should I anticipate floating point shenanigans?

All my values within a Rails application are `BigDecimal` type and I'm seeing some errors (they do have different decimal lengths), hoping it's just my methods and not my object types.

Answer (score 37):

There are two common pitfalls when working with floating point arithmetic.

**The first problem** is that Ruby floating points have fixed precision. In practice this will either be 1) no problem for you or 2) disastrous, or 3) something in between. Consider the following:

```
# float
1.0e+25 - 9999999999999999900000000.0
#=> 0.0

# bigdecimal
BigDecimal("1.0e+25") - BigDecimal("9999999999999999900000000.0")
#=> 100000000
```

A precision difference of 100 million! Pretty serious, right?

Except the precision error is only about 0.000000000000001% of the original number. It really is up to you to decide if this is a problem or not. But the problem is removed by using `BigDecimal` because it has arbitrary precision. Your only limit is memory available to Ruby.

**The second problem** is that floating points cannot express all fractions accurately. In particular, they have problems with *decimal* fractions, because floats in Ruby (and most other languages) are *binary* floating points. For example, the decimal fraction `0.2` is an eternally-repeating binary fraction (`0.001100110011...`). This can never be stored accurately in a binary floating point, no matter what the precision is.

This can make a big difference when you're rounding numbers. Consider:

```
# float
(0.29 * 50).round
#=> 14  # not correct

# bigdecimal
(BigDecimal("0.29") * 50).round
#=> 15  # correct
```

A `BigDecimal` can describe *decimal* fractions precisely. However, there are fractions that cannot be described precisely with a decimal fraction either. For example `1/9` is an eternally-repeating decimal fraction (`0.1111111111111...`).

Again, this will bite you when you round a number. Consider:

```
# bigdecimal
(BigDecimal("1") / 9 * 9 / 2).round
#=> 0  # not correct
```

In this case, using decimal floating points will **still** give a rounding error.

Some conclusions:

- Decimal floats are awesome if you do calculations with decimal fractions (money, for example).
- Ruby's `BigDecimal` also works well if you need arbitrary precision floating points, and don't really care if they are decimal or binary floating points.
- If you work with (scientific) data, you're typically dealing with fixed precision numbers; Ruby's built-in floats will probably suffice.
- You can never expect arithmetic with *any* kind of floating point to be precise in all situations.

Comment: "In practice this will either be 1) no problem for you or 2) disastrous, or 3) something in between"  - love how you've narrowed this down :)