# Is there documentation for the Rails column types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for more than the simple type listing [that is found on this page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column):

> :primary_key, :string, :text, :integer, :float, :decimal, :datetime, :timestamp, :time, :date, :binary, :boolean

But is there any documentation that actually *defines* these fields?

Specifically:

- What's the difference between `:string` and `:text`?
- Between `:float` and `:decimal`?
- What are the distinguishing features of `:time`, `:timestamp`, and `:datetime`?

Are the nuances of these types documented anywhere?

EDIT: **Points of DB-platform implementations are irrelevant to the question I'm trying to ask.**  If, say, `:datetime` does not have a defined intended meaning in Rails documentation, then what do db-adapter-writers go by when choosing a corresponding column type?

Comment: What are those types of, excuse my choice of words, _things_, called? Like, are they fields or attributes or what. I was searching for other _things_ other than `:string` and `:text` and I couldn't find any other than this. So, I was just wondering for future reference.

Comment: @l1zZY, the term you may be looking for is "data types."

Answer (score 409, accepted):

Guidelines built from personal experience:

- **String**:

  - Limited to 255 characters (depending on DBMS)
  - Use for short text fields (names, emails, etc)
- **Text**:

  - Unlimited length (depending on DBMS)
  - Use for comments, blog posts, etc. General rule of thumb: if it's captured via textarea, use Text. For input using textfields, use string.
- **Integer**:

  - Whole numbers
- **Float**:

  - Decimal numbers stored with floating point precision
  - Precision is fixed, which can be problematic for some calculations; generally no good for math operations due to inaccurate rounding.
- **Decimal**:

  - Decimal numbers stored with precision that varies according to what is needed by your calculations; use these for math that needs to be accurate
  - See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039650/ruby-bigdecimal-sanity-check-floating-point-newb) post for examples and an in-depth explanation on the differences between floats and decimals.
- **Boolean**:

  - Use to store true/false attributes (i.e. things that only have two states, like on/off)
- **Binary**:

  - Use to store images, movies, and other files in their original, raw format in chunks of data called *blobs*
- **:primary_key**

  - This datatype is a placeholder that Rails translates into whatever primary key datatype your database of choice requires (i.e. `serial primary key` in postgreSQL). Its use is somewhat complicated and not recommended.
  - Use model and migration constraints (like `validates_uniqueness_of` and `add_index` with the `:unique => true` option) instead to simulate primary key functionality on one of your own fields.
- **Date**:

  - Stores only a date (year, month, day)
- **Time**:

  - Stores only a time (hours, minutes, seconds)
- **DateTime**:

  - Stores both date and time
- **Timestamp**

  - Stores both date and time
  - Note: For the purposes of Rails, both Timestamp and DateTime mean the same thing (use either type to store both date and time). For the TL;DR description of why both exist, read the bottom paragraph.

These are the types about which confusion often exists. I really don't know why there isn't official documentation about these. Also, I imagine these database adapters you referred to were written by the same people who wrote Rails, so they probably didn't need any documentation to go by when they were writing the adapters.

Note: the presence of both `:DateTime` and `:Timestamp`, from what I can find, is included by Rails mostly for compatibility with database systems. For instance, MySQL's `TIMESTAMP` datatype is stored as a unix timestamp. Its valid range goes from 1970 to 2038, and the time is stored as the number of seconds that have elapsed since the last [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Computing), which is supposedly standard, but in practice can differ from system to system. MySQL later introduced the `DATETIME` datatype, which is stored as seconds (with optional fractional seconds as of 5.6.4) since "1000-01-01 00:00:00", at the cost of a [size increase](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time). The `TIMESTAMP` datatype was retained for backwards compatibility. Other database systems went through similar evolutions. Rails recognized that multiple standards existed, and provided interfaces to both. However, Rails ActiveRecord defaults both `:Timestamp` and `:DateTime` to UTC dates stored in MySql's `DATETIME`, so it makes no functional difference to Rails programmers. These exist so that users who *wish* to differentiate between the two can do so. (For a more in-depth explanation, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928275/in-ruby-on-rails-whats-the-difference-between-datetime-timestamp-time-and-da) SO answer).

Comment: That is an awesome writeup, @aguazales.  It seems like a huge oversight that the Rails documentation doesn't have something like this.

Comment: Thanks :) And I completely agree, ActiveRecord and its datatypes are so important to Rails, idk why this isn't standard documentation.

Comment: A description of `:primary_key` has also been added to the list

Comment: Text isn't always unlimited length - in MySQL it's limited to about 16kb. There are MEDIUMTEXT and LONGTEXT database types if you need more than 16kb.

Comment: I voted your comment up because textfields aren't unlimited length. However, according to the [MySQL 5.7 manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html), the default TEXT type can hold about 64kb, not 16 as you claim. I assumed for the sake of brevity that we were dealing with text segments less than 64kb, which is why I didn't address that in my answer. The answer risks becoming convoluted to the point of uselessness if everything is qualified with statements that only apply in rare cases. Thank you for pointing it out though! I enjoy constructive criticism.

Comment: Haegin is correct. We are quashing a bug now that occurs due to a text field blowing out of its 64k limit, so it's not terribly rare.

Comment: This is also a good source [Rails Migration Data Types – MySql – Postgresql – SQLite](http://kiubmen.com/blogging/rails-migration-data-types-mysql-postgresql-sqlite/). I know it's database specific but knowing the actual implementation is still helpful when understanding rails database types.

Comment: binary isn't mentioned here.

Comment: @Nate's resource is no longer available.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, but I think Nate's resource was reposted [here](http://www.wetware.co.nz/2009/04/rails-migration-data-types-mysql-postgresql-sqlite/).

Answer (score 12):

From Rails master branch source code I found:

[abstract mysql_adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb)

```
#activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb

  NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES = {
    primary_key: "bigint auto_increment PRIMARY KEY",
    string:      { name: "varchar", limit: 255 },
    text:        { name: "text", limit: 65535 },
    integer:     { name: "int", limit: 4 },
    float:       { name: "float" },
    decimal:     { name: "decimal" },
    datetime:    { name: "datetime" },
    timestamp:   { name: "timestamp" },
    time:        { name: "time" },
    date:        { name: "date" },
    binary:      { name: "blob", limit: 65535 },
    boolean:     { name: "tinyint", limit: 1 },
    json:        { name: "json" },
  }

  # Maps logical Rails types to MySQL-specific data types.
  def type_to_sql(type, limit = nil, precision = nil, scale = nil, unsigned = nil)
    sql = case type.to_s
    when 'integer'
      integer_to_sql(limit)
    when 'text'
      text_to_sql(limit)
    when 'blob'
      binary_to_sql(limit)
    when 'binary'
      if (0..0xfff) === limit
        "varbinary(#{limit})"
      else
        binary_to_sql(limit)
      end
    else
      super(type, limit, precision, scale)
    end

    sql << ' unsigned' if unsigned && type != :primary_key
    sql
  end    

# and integer ...

  def integer_to_sql(limit) # :nodoc:
    case limit
    when 1; 'tinyint'
    when 2; 'smallint'
    when 3; 'mediumint'
    when nil, 4; 'int'
    when 5..8; 'bigint'
    else raise(ActiveRecordError, "No integer type has byte size #{limit}")
    end
  end

 # and text ..

  def text_to_sql(limit) # :nodoc:
    case limit
    when 0..0xff;               'tinytext'
    when nil, 0x100..0xffff;    'text'
    when 0x10000..0xffffff;     'mediumtext'
    when 0x1000000..0xffffffff; 'longtext'
    else raise(ActiveRecordError, "No text type has byte length #{limit}")
    end
  end

# and binary ...

    def binary_to_sql(limit) # :nodoc:
      case limit
      when 0..0xff;               "tinyblob"
      when nil, 0x100..0xffff;    "blob"
      when 0x10000..0xffffff;     "mediumblob"
      when 0x1000000..0xffffffff; "longblob"
      else raise(ActiveRecordError, "No binary type has byte length #{limit}")
      end
    end
```

the `super` in `type_to_sql` method

```
#activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb
  def type_to_sql(type, limit = nil, precision = nil, scale = nil) #:nodoc:
    type = type.to_sym if type
    if native = native_database_types[type]
      column_type_sql = (native.is_a?(Hash) ? native[:name] : native).dup

      if type == :decimal # ignore limit, use precision and scale
        scale ||= native[:scale]

        if precision ||= native[:precision]
          if scale
            column_type_sql << "(#{precision},#{scale})"
          else
            column_type_sql << "(#{precision})"
          end
        elsif scale
          raise ArgumentError, "Error adding decimal column: precision cannot be empty if scale is specified"
        end

      elsif [:datetime, :time].include?(type) && precision ||= native[:precision]
        if (0..6) === precision
          column_type_sql << "(#{precision})"
        else
          raise(ActiveRecordError, "No #{native[:name]} type has precision of #{precision}. The allowed range of precision is from 0 to 6")
        end
      elsif (type != :primary_key) && (limit ||= native.is_a?(Hash) && native[:limit])
        column_type_sql << "(#{limit})"
      end

      column_type_sql
    else
      type.to_s
    end
  end
```

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.native_database_types`

Answer (score 2):

These are known as "Native Database Types" and are documented [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractMysqlAdapter.html#method-i-native_database_types). To see a list of the available types and their internal definitions, click "on Github" for the [`native_database_types` method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractMysqlAdapter.html#method-i-native_database_types) and find where `NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES` is defined (at the time of writing, `NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES` is defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7c70791470fc517deb7c640bead9f1b47efb5539/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L29)).

P.S. - Despite the existence of great answers on this question, I'm contributing my answer because none of the other answers provided any links to regularly maintained documentation. While I appreciate the advice and code-snippets in the other answers, having a link to formal documentation is useful and more likely to reflect any recent changes.