# the data type of ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

so,I am a beginner,when I study the migration,now I write a migration as follows:

```
create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :uid
    t.string :pwd
    t.string :email
    t.string :qq
    t.integer :integral
    t.timestamps
end
```

But now I want to add a `boolean`filed,I don't know where to find the filed type just as `t.string`.I didn't find this  on the official document.

so who can tell me where I can find all filed type for the ActiveRecord,thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889048/is-there-documentation-for-the-rails-column-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had to go digging in the API documentation but a complete list appears to be here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column

Note that its examples like `td.column(:granted, :boolean)` can also be written as `td.boolean :granted`, as in the 'Short-hand examples' section.