# Rails: make timestamp to look like timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using Ruby on Rails with ActiveRecords. And it really makes me sick about all this datatypes like DateTime, Time etc. I render all data-related things on frontend, so i need just simple int when retrieving Timestamp from DB. Can i do it without having so many `to_int` in my code?

Let's say i have migration like

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.string :crypted_password, null: false
      t.string :password_salt, null: false
      t.string :persistence_token, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Then i do smth like

```
<%= @user.created_at =>
```

I have smth like 2015-02-11 14:11:04 UTC (because it's DateTime to_s in fact). While i need just 1423663864 (so i have to do smth like <%= @user.created_at.to_i =>). So it makes 4(!) conversion:

1. DB 4 bytes int to DB string
2. DB string to Ruby DateTime
3. DateTime to int (the 4 bytes i had on first step)
4. Ruby int to Ruby string

Comment: That's not very clear. What database system are you using ? What are the data types used in your database and in active record ? and give a code example of the problem you're facing, and what the desired output would be

Comment: you need to change the date format, which you want to show in the view?

Comment: You can simply save the datevalues as seconds since epoch which is an integer value. You can then decide how you want to format the value in your views.

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk, added some more info

Comment: @amtest, no. I need it to work just with numbers.

Comment: @dennis it's not a solution. E.g. if i want to use some DB triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change the default output format of your dates to a unix timestamp representation :

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%s"
```

According to the [strftime documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) :

> Seconds since the Unix Epoch:
>   %s - Number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Read more about how `datetime` and `timestamp` types are handled in rails [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889048/is-there-documentation-for-the-rails-column-types) (at the end of the answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file in config/initializers, let's say... date_format.rb with this:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d-%m-%Y"
```

Then when you print a date, it will show with the format you wrote.
P.D.: I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: It's still Date. Just changes to_s method.

Comment: Set a format without blanks. You can print the string to a variable, and then convert it to int... But yeah, you're getting a lot of conversions so I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

In ruby you can call `to_i` or `to_f` on a Date/Time/DateTime object to get the "seconds since epoch" value in integer or float format.