# What causes CSV export cut off text in Ruby 2.0.0/Postgres 9.3/Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, csv

We just found out that CSV export cut off text in one field. Here is the original text for CSV export (from a text field of postgres 9.3):

```
@payable_approved_unpaid, @payable_paid, @payable_po_unpaid = {}, {}, {}
models.each do |m|
     @payable_po_unpaid[m.id.to_s] = PurchaseOrderx::Order.where(project_id: m.id).sum('po_total') - PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest.where(project_id: m.id).where(resource_string: 'purchase_orderx/orders').sum('amount')
     @payable_paid[m.id.to_s] = PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest.where(project_id: m.id).where(wf_state: :paid).sum('amount')
     @payable_approved_unpaid[m.id.to_s] = PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest.where(project_id: m.id).where('approved = ? AND wf_state != ?', true, :paid).sum('amount')
end
```

Here is what we get from CSV:

```
@payable_approved_unpaid, @payable_paid, @payable_po_unpaid = {}, {}, {}

models.each do |m|

     @payable_po_unpaid[m.id.to_s] = PurchaseOrderx::Order.where(project_id: m.id).sum('po_total') - PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest.where(project_id: m.id).wher
```

In the same file, there are fields which is much long than this and there is no problem. We have been using the export for a long time and this is first time we are losing text. What could cause the cut=off of text in CSV export?

Here is the method for CSV export, argument_value is the field with cut-off text. In debug, we verified that full context of the column has been assigned to CSV before exporting:

```
def self.to_csv
      CSV.generate do |csv|
        header = ['id', 'engine_name', 'engine_version', 'argument_name', 'argument_value', 'last_updated_by_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'brief_note', 'global']        
        csv << header
        i = 1
        all.each do |config|
          base = OnboardDatax.engine_config_class.find_by_id(config.engine_config_id)
          row = Array.new
          row << i
          row << (base.global ? nil : base.engine.name)
          row << base.engine_version
          row << base.argument_name
          row << (config.custom_argument_value.present? ? config.custom_argument_value : base.argument_value)
          row << config.last_updated_by_id
          row << config.created_at
          row << config.updated_at
          row << base.brief_note
          row << (base.global ? 't' : 'f')
          csv << row
          i += 1
        end
      end
```

If wrapping the whole text with quotation mark, then the column can be exported to CSV in its entirety.

Comment: How are you checking the file - could it be an issue with the program you are using to open the csv?

Comment: By the way, the `i += 1` fiddling can be accomplished more idiomatically using  `all.each.with_index(1) do |config, i|`.

Comment: `Frederick Cheung`, MS excel is being used to open the csv file, as we always do.

Comment: I'd check with something lower level (eg a text editor first). Excel sometimes does weird things

Comment: `Federick Cheung`, you are right that excel does wired things. When opening csv with notepad++, the full context appears. If you post an answer, will mark it. BTW what's the editor you recommend for opening CSV? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> What could cause the cut=off of text in CSV export?

```
puts File.read('your_cutoff_text.txt').size

--output:--
256
```

[Rails column types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889048/is-there-documentation-for-the-rails-column-types):

```
String:
Limited to 255 characters (depending on DBMS)
```

My OS automatically adds a newline to the end of a file, so your cutoff text contains exactly 255 characters.

> In the same file, there are fields which is much long than this and
>   there is no problem.

[Rails column types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889048/is-there-documentation-for-the-rails-column-types):

```
Text: 
Unlimited length (depending on DBMS)
```

Comment: `7stud`, not sure why cut off at 256th for this row only. The db field is `text`. Also the next 2nd row after cut-off one has way more texts (more than 700 at least) in the same column.

Comment: @user938363,  For rows where `config.custom_argument_value` is present, I suggest you print out both `config.custom_argument_value` and `base.argument_value`, or print out a flag indicating which one is being used to produce the value.