# In ruby on rails how would I best go about storing ONLY hours and minutes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

What I need in my database could be made as such:

**Migration**

```
start_time_hours:integer
start_time_minutes:integer

end_time_hours:integer
end_time_minutes:integer
```

This is for saving a schedule that repeats every week and needs no other information than this. (An enum for the day, but this seems irrelevant).

Is there a way of doing this that is more the "Rails way", and less hacky?

```
start_time:time
end_time:time
```

perhaps?

And (how) would this work more efficient with forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useful information: (source: [Is there documentation for the Rails column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889048/is-there-documentation-for-the-rails-column-types))

- **Date**      : Stores only a date (year, month, day)
- **Time**      : Stores only a time (hours, minutes, seconds)
- **DateTime**  : Stores both date and time
- **Timestamp** : Stores both date and time

Note: For the purposes of Rails, both Timestamp and DateTime mean the same thing (use either type to store both date and time). For the TL;DR description of why both exist, read the bottom paragraph (in source link).

So yes, you can do something like

```
start_time:time
end_time:time
```

in forms you can use an input type time

```
<input type="time" name="start_time">
```

i think this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
start_time: time
duration_in_minutes: integer
```

In the form you have options, show start and end time and calculate the minutes before saving or show start time plus a pull down with the duration in minutes of the meeting.