# How to add hours and minutes that are stored as strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add hours and minutes that are stored in the database like this:

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | user_id | time  |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       4 | 03:15 |
|  2 |       4 | 02:22 |
+----+---------+-------+
```

The `time` field is a `string`. How can I add the hours and minutes expressed by the strings like `05:37`?

I tried this

```
current_user.table.pluck(:time).sum(&:to_f)
```

but the output is only `5`.

Comment: Perhaps you should change the format of the saved data. If you used an int for minutes this would be much easier. This would also enable you to filter (e.g. everything less than 1 hour) or sum up values.

Comment: `current_user.table` probably refers to the user table and not to the table where the times are saved.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add times without dates, so I'm assuming it's more like a duration? Like your measuring time for running laps or something? Also look at the database types Rails supports e.g. `Time`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889048/is-there-documentation-for-the-rails-column-types.

Comment: @mbuechmann the `table` is `times` table where user can saving their `times`

Comment: _"The time field is a string"_ – why? You should save data in an appropriate format. If this is elapsed time, you could for example store the number of minutes (which can easily be converted into HH:MM for displaying purposes).

Comment: @Sree _"It doesn't make sense to add times without dates"_ – opening hours or alarm clocks are typical examples for times without dates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read the times from your table into an array you obtain something like

```
arr = ["03:15", "02:22"]
```

You could then write

```
arr.sum do |s|
  h, m = s.split(':').map(&:to_i)
  60*h + m
end.divmod(60).join(':')
  #=> "5:37"
```

See [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sum) (introduced in MRI v2.4) and [Integer#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-divmod). To support Ruby versions earlier than 2.4 use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) in place of `Array#sum`.

The three steps are as follows.

```
mins = arr.sum do |s|
  h, m = s.split(':').map(&:to_i)
  60*h + m
end
  #=> 337
hm = mins.divmod(60)
  #=> [5, 37]
hm.join(':')
  #=> "5:37"
```

Comment: You can use `sum` instead of `reduce`.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan, much better. I did an edit. I can’t test now but it looks OK. Btw, I picked up a downvote. I wonder if it was because I named my variable for totals minutes `secs` (which you changed—thanks). Sleep awaits.

Comment: Downvote for variable naming? I don't think so, but you never know.

Comment: Hey @CarySwoveland Would you please suggest me how I subtract like I need to subtract `10:15`  to subtract `05:05`, please advise how

Comment: @user9769384 it works the same way: (1) convert each value to the number of minutes, i.e. `10:15` → `615` and `05:05` → `305` (2) subtract the minutes `615 - 305` → `310` (3) convert the result to HH:MM `310.divmod(60)` → `[5, 10]` which is `05:10`

Answer (score 6):

Please check this sample of summing time in ruby:

```
require 'time'

t = Time.parse("3:15")
puts t.strftime("%H:%M")

t2 = Time.parse("02:22")
puts t2.strftime("%H:%M")
t3 = t.to_i + t2.to_i

puts Time.at(t3).utc.strftime("%H:%M")
```

This is fast sum of times below 24 hour span. For correct solution for every case please check @Cary code above.

Here is a small Ruby Gem made from @Cary code sample which extends Ruby Array class with method sum_strings in example like:
 `["12:23","23:30","1:2"].sum_strings(':')`  will result as "`36:55`"

Gem https://github.com/nezirz/sum_strings/

Sample project with using Gem: https://github.com/nezirz/use_sum_strings

Comment: I suggest you use `strptime` rather than `parse`. My standard example for illustrating the problem with `parse` is `Time.parse("It was a tough week for Elizabeth May.") #=> 2018-05-01 00:00:00 -0700`. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: Hold the phone! Try changing the first statement to `t = Time.parse("23:15")`. You should get `"25:37"` as the total, but being more than 24 hours you have a problem.

Comment: Or `Time.parse('27:15')` which results in an `ArgumentError` – the OP didn't say that the values don't exceed 24 hours.

Comment: `Hold the phone` :) neat phrase