# Is specifying floating-point type sufficient to guarantee same results?

Tags: floating-point, precision

I'm writing a specification that describes some arithmetic that will be performed by software. The intention is that I can hand this spec to two different programmers (who use potentially different languages and/or architectures) and when I feed some input into their programs, they will both *always* spit out the same result.

For instance, if the spec says "add 0.5 to the result", this can be a problem. Depending on the floating point storage method, 0.5 could be represented as 0.4999999135, or 0.500000138, etc.

What is the best way to specify the rules here so that things are consistent across the board? Can I just say "All numbers must be represented in [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) 64-bit format"? Or is it better to say something like "All numbers must be first scaled by 1000 and computed using fixed-point arithmetic"?

This is a little different from most floating-point questions I've come across since the issue is repeatability across platforms, not the overall precision.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reproducibility of floating point operation result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952480/reproducibility-of-floating-point-operation-result)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IEEE 754-2008 clause 11 describes what is necessary for reproducible floating-point results. This is largely:

- Bindings from the programming language to IEEE 754 operations (e.g., `a*b` performs the floating-point multiplication specified by IEEE 754).
- Ways to specify that reproducible results are desired. E.g., disable default language permissions to use wider precision than the nominal types of objects.
- Accurate conversions to and from external decimal character sequences.
- Avoiding some of the fancier features of IEEE 754.

These requirements are poorly supported in today’s compilers.

Adding .5 will not be a problem. All normal floating-point implementations represent .5 exactly and add it correctly. What will be a problem is that a language implementation may add .5 and keep the result precisely (more precisely than a usual `double`) while another implementation rounds the result to `double`. If math library routines are used (such as `cos` and `log`), that is another problem, because they are hard to compute well, and different implementations provide different approximations.

IEEE 754 is a good specification. Ideally, you would specify that implementations of your specification conform to IEEE 754.

Comment: It's interesting that most CPUs and programming languages claim IEEE 754 compliance. Yet they can all use different rules for intermediate calculations and rounding. Those who are relying on floating-point determinism have to jump through all kinds of hoops to keep these rules in line. Sounds painful.

Comment: @Tim The last general-purpose desktop processor that did not provide everything needed for “IEEE 754 compliance” must have been made around 2003-2004 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2 ). The fault lies entirely on compilation chains. The authors of those may themselves place the blame on the comparative lack of interest from users on results reproducibility as opposed to performance, compatibility with old ABIs, compatibility of generated code with pre-2003 processors, …