# Casting float to int inconsistent across MinGw and Clang

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

Using C++, I'm trying to cast a `float` value to an `int` using these instructions :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float NbrToCast = 1.8f;
    int TmpNbr = NbrToCast * 10;
    std::cout << TmpNbr << "\n";
}
```

I understand the value `1.8` cannot be precisely represented as a `float` and is actually stored as `1.79999995`.

Thus, I would expect that multiplying this value by ten, would result to `17.99999995` and then casting it to an `int` would give `17`.

When compiling and running this code with `MinGW` (v4.9.2 32bits) on Windows 7, I get the expected result (`17`).

When compiling and running this code with `CLang` (v600.0.57) on my Mac (OS X 10.11), I get `18`as a result, which is not what I was expecting but which seems more *correct* in a mathematical way !

Why do I get this difference ?

Is there a way to have a consistent behavior no matter the OS or the compiler ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494237/floating-point-mismatch-between-compilers-visual-studio-2010-and-gcc

Comment: Try changing the last line to `std::cout <<  std::precision(20) << TmpNbr << "\n";`

Comment: @RichardCritten: `TmpNbr` is `int`, then what is the point of `std::precision(20)`?

Comment: There are a number of IEEE-754 [rounding rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules); it's possible the default each compiler is using is different. Try setting the rounding mode (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round) and see what happens?

Comment: @Nawaz sorry I was having a stupid moment.

Comment: With floating point, there's rarely a way to get completely consistent behaviour between platforms.

Comment: @Yuushi Much more likely than a difference in rounding mode is a difference in value for `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

Comment: My first assumption is that it is a compiler optimization. I suggest CLang computes the result at compile time. Would be interesting to know, what the output would be if TmpNbr would be a float also.

Answer (score -1):

Like Yuushi said in the comments, I guess the rounding rules may differ for each compiler. Having a portable solution on such a topic probably means you need to write your own rounding method.

So in your case you probably need to check the value of the digit after 7 and increment the value or not. Let's say something like:

```
int main() {
    float NbrToCast = 1.8f;
    float TmpNbr = NbrToCast * 10;
    std::cout << RoundingFloatToInt(TmpNbr) << "\n";
}

int RoundingFloatToInt(const float &val)
{
  float intPart, fractPart;
  fractpart = modf (val, &intpart);
  int result = intPart;
  if (fractpart > 0.5) 
  {
    result++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

(code not tested at all but you have the idea)

If you need performance, it's probably not great but I think it should be portable.