# Is floating point representation compiler-dependent in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point

The question is in the title. It seems that the software I deliver to my customer has varying behaviors depending on wether some parameters passed as integers or as floats. I build a DLL for my customer with MinGW and he integrates it in his Visual Studio project, which uses some other compiler (no idea which, I guess the standard one for VS).

Could it be that floats are represented differently by him than by me ?

Thanks for the heads up,
Charles

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494237/floating-point-mismatch-between-compilers-visual-studio-2010-and-gcc

Comment: In short: Yes it is.

Comment: Generally, linking code compiled with different compilers is not a good idea - there's no guarantee it will work correctly. You should usually always build everything with the *exact* same compiler.

Comment: All Windows compilers are going to use the same representation for `float`, or for `double` -- the one used by the platform.  `long double` does vary.  Passing a `float` to a function that expects an `int` and vice versa will cause all manner of problems.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: If the function signatures are C-compliant, there's no problem.  C++ objects can't be trivially passed around, however.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Great, gotta thank my architect for telling me that beforehand. Oh wait, there is no architect in my project. That's why.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I know. That's why I used words like "generally" and "usually".  In any case, if you just follow the rule of thumb that is "always build everything with the exact same compiler" then you'll never run into (certain kinds of) trouble - which was my main point :)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: But it simply isn't true... what you're saying is that you cannot have any application that is not built with the exact same compiler version that the OS team used, because you are *constantly* calling into Win32 DLLs.  Languages other than C would be completely impossible.  In reality, foreign function interfaces are a thing, and C-compatible signatures are perfectly usable across different compiler vendors, versions, and languages.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I think you know exactly what I'm saying - we both know there's a stable C ABI but not a C++ one. We both know that *iff* you stick to what is guaranteed to be binary compatible you can use whatever compiler. *But* we also both know that sticking to the guaranteed subset can sometimes be tricky (especially for non-expert users), so "use the same compiler for all your code" is a useful guideline that prevents a lot of pain. Why do you argue that it is not?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Designing a system that must be wholly built using a single compiler is incredibly short-sighted and dangerous.  Let me lay out the abbreviated explanation, and you can let me know which step you don't understand. (1) The system is built using a single compiler, ergo (2) The system relies on being built using a single compiler, ergo (3) The system cannot be built using any later compiler version, ergo (4) Components cannot be updated to their latest versions, ergo (5) The system has bugs and security vulnerabilities. QED

Answer (score 4):

Yes, floating point representation is compiler dependent.

In theory you can use `std::numeric_limits` to determine the main aspects of the representation, such as whether it's IEEE 754, or whether it's binary or decimal.

In practice you can't rely on that except for the memory layout, because with a main compiler, g++, the semantics of floating point operations are influenced strongly by the optimization options (e.g., whether `NaN` compares equal to itself or not).

I.e. in practice it's not only compiler dependent but also option-dependent.

Happily compilers for a given platform will generally conform to that platform's standard memory layout for floating point, e.g. IEEE 754 in Windows (the standard originated on the PC platform). And so floating point values should in general work OK when exchanged between g++ and Visual C++, say. One exception is that with g++ `long double` maps to 80-bit IEEE 754, while with Visual C++ it maps to ordinary `double`, i.e. 64-bit, and that *could* conceivably be what makes trouble for you.

Comment: Hmm, is a compiler really allowed to optimise `NaN == NaN` to the extent that the semantics are unpredictable? I doubt it. If IEC 559 is being used then IEC 559 is being used and its rules should be gospel.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In my view it's not allowed. But, it does.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this claim?

Comment: You can just try it.

Comment: I have never witnessed `NaN == NaN` and my computer isn't going to magically change that behaviour now to the extent that I can immediately verify your claim.

Comment: Yes, many versions. As I said, all of them abide by `NaN != NaN`.

Comment: [Here's an answer from jalf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/570694/560648), which he edited after you said the same thing to him. However, in the comments section there, it was already explained to you that with the proper compiler switches the compiler is _required_ to enforce `NaN != NaN`. However, this was five and a half years ago, so perhaps you forgot :)

Comment: Anyway I shall instead use `std::isnan` (or equivalent) in the future where available. Thanks!