# Why is there different asinh output from numpy depending on OS?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, operating-system

I'm trying to keep consistent floating point calculation results across operating systems and I ran across an odd regression regarding numpy and arcsinh when testing on newer systems. Here is a minimal working example that behaves differently across systems.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import struct

from numpy import (array, arcsinh, float32)


def float_to_hex(f):
    return hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', f))[0])


numpy_result = arcsinh(array([3.0], dtype=float32))[0]
print("asinh(3.0):", numpy_result, float_to_hex(numpy_result))
```

On Centos 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 I get the following result:
`asinh(3.0): 1.8184464 0x3fe8c2da`

On Ubuntu 18.04 (and Windows according to a colleague) I get the following result:
`asinh(3.0): 1.8184465 0x3fe8c2db`

It would be great to understand why this is happening and how to get a consistent result across systems. Ideally sticking to a 32-bit floating point solution. Is there some numpy option I'm overlooking that changes across operating systems?

Notably I cannot reproduce this with a C-program. With GLIBC's asinh (of a 32 bit float 3.0) I *always* get the new result of 1.8184465 and it's 0x3fe8c2db hex representation regardless of what system I'm on. This seems to be numpy specific.

My working C example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float value = asinhf(3.0f);
    unsigned int hexValue = *(unsigned int *)&value;
    printf("Plain value: %.7f\n", value);
    printf("Hex value: 0x%8x\n", hexValue);
    return 0;
}
```

I can also verify that the exact same numpy version is being used across systems. In this case it is 1.15.3. The numpy package was installed from wheels everywhere and so the same shared object libraries are installed. For my sanity, I double checked the libraries by running the `file` operation on all of them across all systems.

I believe that according to IEEE 754, the last significant digit of 5 (for arcsinh of 3.0) is correct since it should round away from zero. However, a solution where the result is consistent is more important to me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you also see a difference with 64-bit floating point values of asinh(3)?

Comment: Were some of the systems 32-bit systems and others 64-bit? Were all systems x86-based?

Comment: Can you show the C code you used for testing? Note that if you're doing something like `asinh(3.0)` directly, then `gcc` will use MPFR to make a perfectly correctly-rounded _compile-time_ evaluation, so you wouldn't be touching the libm implementation of `asinh` in that case.

Comment: But in general, it's optimistic to hope for reproducible results across `libm` implementations, even assuming IEEE 754 format. And NumPy is at the mercy of the OS's `libm` here.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17031607/270986) from Eric Postpischil is relevant here: "If math library routines are used (such as cos and log), that is another problem, because they are hard to compute well, and different implementations provide different approximations."

Comment: I get the consistent results across all systems for 64 bit floats. This problem only arises from 32-bit floats but it seems likely due to the fact the last significant digit needed to be rounded from this particular calculation.

Comment: All systems were 64-bit systems and x86-based

Comment: The numpy math libraries used, containing backup arcsinh implementations I found inside the numpy implementation, are identical across systems so I don't know how there would be a compiler or implementation issue. I could maybe see an issue where there is more than one implementation of arcsinh across GLIBC/numpy and one implementation is being used on one system vs a different one on another.

Comment: Those are *backup* implementations, only used if the libm doesn't provide `asinh` directly (which it almost certainly does on your system). And even those backup implementations make calls to other libm functions, like `log1p`, whose backup implementation calls `log`, which doesn't have a backup implementation because it's reliably provided by all math libraries. So the OS libm comes into play no matter what.

Comment: With round-to-nearest-ties-to-even, the correctly rounded 32-bit `float` for `asinh(3)` is that represented by 0x3fe8c2db (1.81844651699066162109375), but it is not because IEEE-754 says you should round away from zero. The rounding rule is user-selectable, and the default is most often to round to the nearest representable value, with ties to the even low bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I dicovered *why* the answer is different across systems and how I did not see it before. However, I'm still not sure how to get consistent results.

As Mark Dickinson pointed out in the comments, something I overlooked was gcc was performing a compile-time optimization with MPFR (multiple-precision floating-point with correct rounding). Running ldd on my resulting binary showed that libm was not being dynamically loaded at all. I recompiled my C example with clang and dynamically linking in `libm` and lo and behold I got the exact same results as I would have done through python/numpy across systems. The result is `asinhf(3.0f);` is rounded down on older systems and rounded up on newer systems.

So this looks like a `libm` library update at some point.

Specifically there was a change that occurred at least between 2.23 and 2.27 of GLIBC.

If anyone has any suggestions for getting consistent rounding across systems I would be very appreciative. I suspect that there maybe incorrect rounding regardless of precision on older systems.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Note that while you have identified the issue in this case, math libraries (the routines that provide `asinh` and such) in general do not conform to IEEE-754. Implementing correct rounding for these routines is hard, and nobody has provably done it for all the math library routines in a normal math library (any of those used by default in the major operating systems, or even in minor operating systems) nor provably done it in a bound run time. (There may be special versions that will sit and churn until they get a proven correctly rounded result, without a known bound on run time.)

Comment: Because of the foregoing, math libraries are implemented using various approximations, which are partly engineering and partly art. Different libraries implemented by different teams get different results. So, as long as numpy and Python are relying on the underlying math library, results may vary across systems.