# Is this deterministic lockstep?

Tags: c++, floating-point, x86, 64-bit, fortran

I have a large Fortran/C++ project that assembles hundreds of Fortran intermediate files into a single executive.  When I monitor some of the global single precision floating point variables, I get different results when I run the executive on a Windows 7 x64 machine vs a Windows XP SP2 x86 machine.  **The differences are as much as 1-2%**.

The project was built on the x86 machine and not rebuilt before testing on the x64 machine, although I am using the exact same compiler (compaq visual fortran 6.6), and development studio (visual studio 6.0), and identical code for both machines.  The x64 machine has a Pentium E5400, the x86 machine has a pentium 4 dual core.  Could this be an example of [Deterministic Lockstep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952480/reproducibility-of-floating-point-operation-result).

I know this is vague - I wish I could provide some code, but there's over 1 million lines.  All of the variables are `REAL*4` and are calculated in the Fortran code several hundred times per second.  The c++ MFC code assembles it into the executive.

Comment: What compiler version are you using?

Comment: Passing [`/Op`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278532%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to the compiler could circumvent the problem you are facing, if you are running a newer compiler [`/arch:IA32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx) will prevent the compiler to emit *SSE{,2}* instructions (which might also cause what is going on).

Comment: Compiler version is 6.6.  Very interesting, thank you for the explanation, I will look into this.

Comment: /Op works, /arch:IA32 gives the error that IA32 is an unrecognized option for /arch.  Just to clarify, these commands prevent the x64 machine from emitting SSE2 instructions?

Comment: No, `/Op` prevents the compiler from emitting optimized floating-point instructions (the program might be slower, but more accurate) - where as `/arch:IA32` says that it shouldn't emit any *SSE{,2}* instructions (since the result of these may differ between architectures).

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction

The difference you are observing are (probably) due to the fact that your executable includes optimized floating-point instructions, and the result of these instructions can be different between different architectures.

---

---

#### Enable *float-point consistency*

> <sup>**Note**: The following only applies to older (6.0) versions of *msvc++*.</sup>

Unless you explicitly tell the compiler that you don't want it to optimize floating-point operations (where the trade-off might be some slight inaccuracy), it will do so.

Passing `/Op` as a flag to the compiler enables the *"'consistency' floating-point model"*; effectively disabling the previous mentioned optimization.

- [**msdn.microsoft.com** - VS6.0 - `/Op` (Improve Float Consistency)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278532%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

The equivalent flag, [`/fp:strict`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx), is the default option in VS2008.

---

---

#### Turn off *SSE2*

> <sup>**Note**: The following only applies to newer versions of *msvc++*.</sup>

Unless you explicitly say that you don't want the *msvc++* to generate *SSE{,2}* instructions for your floating-point calculations, such will be included in your executable.

You can force the compiler to disable generation of *SSE* and *SSE2* instructions by passing the flag `/arch:IA32` to it.

- [msdn.microsoft.com -  **/arch (x86)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Filip, this is great information.  I will compile my several hundred files and retest it.

Comment: Great information, but the results were the exact same after compiling every source file with /Op and rebuilding.

Comment: @AlexB could you create a small *testcase*? All you really need to do is write a simple application that does some floating-point arithmetic, and that shows different behavior on the two architectures.

Comment: Doing this.  You seem to know a lot about Compaq visual fortran compiler options.  Is there a manual of available options?  I can't find anything anywhere...

Comment: @AlexB 5 seconds of simple googling http://jp.xlsoft.com/documents/intel/cvf/cvf_pg.pdf You should have received it when you bought the compiler BTW.

Comment: @VladimirF  I believe the compiler options he was referring to were the cvf compiler options.  I compile the fortran source into intermediates before building the c++ project.  I did not buy the compiler (is it even sold anymore?), it's legacy software that has been here long before me.  Thanks for the document, I guess you're a better googler than me.

Comment: @VladimirF I see - as it happens, these are also cvf compiler options (except /arch:IA32)